# webdriver how to focus on the password (Security controls)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

in a login page, i want to use sendKeys to password input
but the "sendkeys" doesn't work; 
how should i do? 
here is html

```
<fieldset class="txt" id="psd">
<label>password：</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
IntPassGuardCtrl("logpswd", "2", "chklogon()",Ipsdstyle");</script>
<span id="logpswd_pgc">
<embed id="logpswd" type="application/x-pass-guard" input0="0" class="psdstyle"></span>
<input name="LOG_PSWD" type="hidden" id="LOG_PSWD">                      </fieldset>
```

1. someone said can use JNA ,but the partial i do not know much.
2. the password control can use mouse click,then focus on; and use the
   keybord input infomation;
3. so i want to use mouse click the control,but use webdriver actions
   doesn't work, do you have some ways to solve the problem?

Comment: what is the error statement you are getting?

Comment: this is code is messy!! Please edit your code and put your selenium code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application uses an embeded object to capture the password field. Unfortunately, the web browser (and thus WebDriver) doesn't know how to interact with the field since its not standard.

However, there might be a chance to do what you need to do. It looks like your HTML includes a hidden input field that might be tied to the embeded object. The embeded object might just set the value of the (encrypted?) password in the `input#LOG_PSWD` element. If this is the case, you can use WebDriver's executeScript method to inject the value of the password.

I don't know what language bindings you use, but this is how you would write it in Ruby:

```
password = "some$3cretP@ssword"
hidden_password = @driver.find_element(:id => "LOG_PSWD")
@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1], arguments[2])", hidden_password, "value", password)
```

Then try to login from there. More than likely the password text will not show up in the control itself since you are injecting it directly to the hidden input.

Give that a shot and let us know what happens. If you can give us more information about the embeded object, we might be able to find some other workarounds if this one doesn't work.